# XMPP: Make client appear online only to other instances of that client

Tags: xmpp

I'd like to use XMPP as the message bus for a desktop application. As the application would use the users existing XMPP account (GTalk or the like) and doesn't provide IM service I would like to make instances of my client invisible to other XMPP clients.

To do this I'm considering using client service discovery and privacy lists to block outgoing presence notifications to the full JIDs of clients other my own. I do however doubt the scalability and robustness of this approach. Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

**EDIT:**

I'm now thinking the closest I can get to this behaviour is to set a presence of away with a negative priority. This will hopefully minimise user confusion and work fairly universally.

Comment: Then you might find parts of this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10405658/15996

Answer (score 0):

[XEP-0126](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0126.html) doesn't have the tools you need, since there's no way you'll find out about the other clients to which you have to direct presence... because they're invisible.

How about if all of your clients join a [MUC](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) room?

Comment: I glossed over the details a bit - I thought I'd be able to block all outgoing presence, go available, use disco to find all clients that aren't mine, then switch to blocking presence to those specific full-JIDs (with resource) and then resend available. Then update the privacy list as further presence stanzas come in from clients other than my own.

I don't think GTalk supports privacy lists though so that is now out. I'll have to have a think about how I could use a MUC instead - thanks.

Comment: Why is that? By my reading of the specs the initial blocking of outgoing presence shouldn't affect incoming presence. If the presence lacks a `<c/>` then that full JID could have been blocked on the privacy list. If the presence has a `<c/>` an `<iq/>` exchange for the client to client disco request would not have been impeded by outgoing presence being blocked on the privacy list.

Comment: Beyond GTalk not supporting privacy lists, the only thing I can see that might have fouled up this approach (beyond it's clumsiness) is if privacy lists take affect on bare JIDs rather than full JIDs. Since they can be activated on a per-stream basis I assumed that isn't the case - can you clarify that for me?

Comment: If it's your client on the other side, you're not going to get presence from it, so the <c/> tag doesn't help you.  Disco#items to your own bare JID usually doesn't respond with a list of resources, and disco#items to someone else's JID SHOULD NOT return their resources, since that would be a presence leak.

Comment: I said I would only _initially_ be blocking outbound presence before switching to blocking presence to specific full JIDs.

Comment: Oh!  You're going to send a big block list with every full JID from every resource you've received presence from (and for which you're in the 'both' state, since you won't get presence from 'from' state contacts, and 'to' state contacts aren't going to receive your presence).  Then send undirected presence.  What happens when someone else comes on line?

Comment: This might make my intent clearer - the reason for the initial block all outbound presence (at the start of a stream) was to try to avoid the client blipping on and then off line. Once the initial round of collecting presences from clients other than my own is over and the client is blocking outbound presence to only a subset, there is no way I can see of preventing a blip. So to answer your question, when one of my clients goes online it is business as usual and when a foreign client comes online, it momentarily sees my client before it is sent directed presence and added to the privacy list.

Comment: I'm now convinced this is a horrible solution though - it's cumbersome and would really eat bandwidth with a significant number of contacts.

I don't think there is a 'good' solution for using XMPP (or I suppose more properly, reusing XMPP-IM) the way I'd like. "Away" with negative priority is an 'okay' solution though so I'll prototype with that and see how awful or otherwise it is in practice.